# Nodejs Promise concept

Tags: node.js, callback, promise

I have 2 functions for creating CSV file and putting the same in a folder and my requirement is to synchronize the operation. Once file created the same will move to the folder location.
  can anyone provide the proper syntax for the same.

```
 function createCSV(){}
 function placeToFolder(){}
```

Answer (score 0):

Promise in general helps with asynchronous operations and makes the code more readable than callbacks. You generally have to promisify your functions in order to use Promise, for example.

```
Promise.resolve()
.then(() => {
   return createCSV()
})
.then(() => {
   return placeToFolder()
})
.then(() => {
})
```

Here your functions return Promise object and wait for the promise to be fulfilled. After that it will continue with the next then.